# Linksys admin password change with special character

Tags: wireless-networking, router, passwords, special-characters

I just changed my Linksys router (WRT110, latest firmware 1.0.07) password to one containing one special accented character (`é` in this occurence), among the 22 characters (all others lowercase alphabetical). I'm certain that the password is right, because I typed it in cleartext before and then pasted it into the fields.

The password change succeeded, but now I can't login anymore, and I want to avoid doing a reset.

I couldn't find any resource regarding special characters in Linksys admin passwords, or perhaps a length limit that I didn't notice. Could someone point me in the right direction / offer reasons as to why I can't login?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities I can think of:

1. The system sanitizes the strings to weed out special characters and this got either removed or converted to a normal letter (probably `e`). Try logging in with both options.
2. The character got scrambled (['mojibake'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)) by the firmware. In this case, you would have to deliberately "corrupt" that character in the same way to find out what it was converted into.

Comment: I tried the password without the `é`, with an `e` instead, with `&eacute;`, `%E9` and `%e9`. How else could it be scrambled?

Comment: If you switch code pages it can be transformed into totally different symbols. I'm trying to find a utility to do so, but it appears to require programming. You might ask on the programmers' site if they know of a place/list of equivalents for é in different code pages.

Comment: @Lazlo - You might have to accept the only solution is to reset the device.  I encourage you to learn from this mistake and backup the settings of your router.  This way a reset isn't a problem.

Comment: An é can be typed as a single character (`LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE`, Unicode: U+00E9) but also as (`LATIN SMALL LETTER E`, U+0065 + `COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT`, Unicode: U+0301). Some systems sanitise one form into the other. The end result is visually the same: é vs é.